# How to tell which data file is opened by an application

Tags: file, powershell

If I open *test.txt* in Notepad and than use `handle.exe` I see many different entries under *notepad.exe*, but *test.txt* is not among them. `Get-Process` or `gwmi win32_process` does not seem to return any relevant info either.

Is there a way to tell which actual data file an application has open? In case of notepad it would be a text file, but generally it could be any type of file opened by an application made to handle it.

I'd prefer an answer usable in PowerShell scripts.

Comment: `handle` doesn't show open handles, because `notepad` opens the file, reads its content into memory and then closes it. You can only detect files that are currently being kept open, not files that have been opened at some point in history.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So there is no way to tell if it's safe to kill the notepad.exe process without loosing unsaved data?

Comment: That's correct. Or at least no way that I am aware of.

Comment: You could use CloseMainWindow() to close notepad, and if notepad has unsaved changes it won't kill the process but raise a save prompt. If it doesn't have unsaved changes it should just close.  This doesn't solve the issue of how to save the open file using powershell, but it could be a way to check for unsaved changes before killing the process.  Get-Process notepad | % { $_.CloseMainWindow() }

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in luck. I just saw this blog post come out this weekend. I think it provides what you're looking for.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/01/weekend-scripter-determine-process-that-locks-a-file.aspx